# grails PagedResultList wrong ordering in UnitTest

Tags: grails

the following controller action return posts in the expected order (decreasing by id) when running the application:

```
def list() {
   PagedResultList posts = Post.createCriteria().list(max: 5, offset: params.offset) {
    if (params.searchTag) {
            tag {
                eq ("name", params.searchTag)
            }
        }
        order("id", "desc")
    }
    [posts: posts, total: posts.totalCount]
}
```

But the unit testing test fails because posts are not returned in the expected order:

```
def “list returns the posts in the correct order”(){
    given:
    def p1 = new Post(title: 'p1', email: 'aaa@aaa.com', content: 'xx').save()
    def p2 = new Post(title: 'p2', email: 'aaa@aaa.com', content: 'xx').save()

    when:
    def model = controller.list()

    then:
    p2.id > p1.id
    model.posts.iterator().next().title == 'p2' //fails: expected p2 got p1
}
```

Any reason why the test fails?

Comment: What id does each of the post objects get?

Comment: p1 id=1, p2 id=2. I've updated the test to reflect that